# Multiprocessing in a for loop and conditions?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list of images (called `screens`), and I am taking screenshot of current window and then comparing this screenshot in OpenCV to list to know which screen is opened. I am doing this using for loop but comparing one image at a time makes my software slow. So, I switched to multiprocessing. below is the code for it:

```
def cpu_bound(template):
    for i in range(len(screens)):
        #compare_images is function to find similarity
        result= compare_images(screen[i],template)
        if result is True:
            return i
    return -1

def find_screen(template):
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            i=pool.map(cpu_bound, template)
            return i
```

To `find_screen` I am passing the screenshot, but in multiprocessing I am getting error that input images does not have same dimensions on this line:

```
result= compare_images(screens[i],template)
```

Although the loop without multiprocessing is working fine. What mistake I am making in implementation of multiprocessing?

Comment: Apologize. Fixed the indentations.

Comment: What is `template` and `screens`? Please post some form of a [mre] so we can productively help

Comment: template is the screenshot taken of the current window, screens is list to which i am comparing screenshot to find similarity

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map a function (`cpu_bound`) on a single value (`template`), and the function itself does a loop (on all `screens`). That's not going to work.

Instead, use `compare_images` directly:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    result = pool.map(lambda screen: compare_images(screen, template), screens)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pool one by one. Here is an example on that.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def func(x, found):
    if x == found:
        return True
    else: 
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asd = [1, 2, 3]
    to_be_found = 3
    f = partial(func, to_be_found)
    with Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(f, asd))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you got it the other way around. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) takes a function and an iterable and runs that function ***on each element of the iterable***. But you are passing the `template` image as the iterable so you're getting this weird error. You probably meant to do:

```
i = pool.map(cpu_bound, screens)
```

Which will require you to change `cpu_bound` a bit:

```py
def cpu_bound(screen):
    #compare_images is function to find similarity
    result = compare_images(screen, template)
    if result is True:
        return screen
    return -1
```

---

That is assuming you are using global variables. If that's not the case, you can use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead to pass multiple arguments. `cpu_bound` will be:

```
def cpu_bound(screen, template):
    ...
```

And you will call it:

```py
from itertools import repeat
...
i = pool.starmap(cpu_bound, zip(screens, repeat(template)))
```